# Riemann Integrability & Darboux Integrability

Tags: real-analysis

> Fix a function $f$. For each partition P, the different choices of
> $x_k$ give different values of the Riemann Sum $S$. On the other hand,
> there is a unique upper sum and a unique lower sum for this P.

I have a question about the last sentence:

> On the other hand,
> there is a unique upper sum and a unique lower sum for this P.

Does this mean that no matter what my P is, there's an unique upper and lower sum? But this is false, right? because $\sup_{x\in[t_{k-1},t_k]}f(x) $ depends on how I choose P. Or did I misunderstand the sentence?

Comment: It is saying that given a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$, you will get a unique upper sum and lower sum, which is dependent on the choice of $P$. That is to say, your choice of partition $P$ will never give two different upper sums or two different lower sums.

Comment: The words "for this $P$" indicate that the author is only talking about one partition...